# Why does generics in java collections so strange?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-construction

For example check method in java.util.Collections

```
 public static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Why can I define it this way:

```
 public static <T> int binarySearch(List<T> list, T key, Comparator<T> c)
```

Why does this will not work in java?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You *could* define it that way, but then that wouldn't let you search a `List<Circle>` using a `Comparator<Shape>`, for example.

Basically, the variance being expressed here allow for more flexibility while maintaining type safety.

Comment: to cover your example I can define
public static <T> int binarySearch(List<T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c) 
it is still different from one in JDK

Comment: @yura: Yes, but then you can't use it if you *have* a `List<? extends Shape>` and a `Comparator<Shape>`, can you? The JDK version is the most flexible safe way of expressing it.

Answer (score 0):

To amplify [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471184/why-does-generics-in-java-collections-so-strange/4471211#4471211)'s answer a bit, Java's generics are not like C++ templates.  Some of the design decisions (like the type erasure) for generics, made for backward compatibility of the JVM itself, lead to awkward syntax and complicated use cases.  [You can read about some of these here.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255.html)

Comment: The fact that generics aren't covariant (and the wildcard syntax that lets you _safely_ do what you want anyway) doesn't have anything to do with type erasure or backward compatibility.